# How to insert lines with numbers from X to Y into another file after line Z?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I created two files:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" > 123.txt
echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne" > abc.txt
```

I want to get the file `123.txt` with the following contents:

```
1
2
3
b
c
d
4
5
```

So in other words insert the rows with numbers from 2 to 4 of the file `abc.txt` into the file `123.txt` after the third line.

I have reviewed the many similar questions here, but did not find a suitable answer. Nevertheless I got the lines:

```
sed -n '2,4p' abc.txt
```

and put some text into the file after the third line:

```
sed -i '3a\mytext' 123.txt
```

How to do this using the previous command stdout or/and a `sed`/`awk` single command?

Comment: Not an elegant solution. But still can be done as a single command. `head -n +3 123.txt > tmp && cat abc.txt >> tmp && tail -n +2 123.txt >> tmp && mv tmp 123.txt`

Comment: @Ramesh I agree with you. Only corrected your command because it gives the wrong result. `head -3 123.txt > tmp && tail -4 abc.txt | head -3 >> tmp && tail -2 123.txt >> tmp && mv tmp 123.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your system has the GNU version of `sed`, you can use the GNU extension `r` command:

```
r filename
    As a GNU extension, this command accepts two addresses.

    Queue the contents of filename to be read and inserted into the
    output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input 
    line is read. Note that if filename cannot be read, it is treated as 
    if it were an empty file, without any error indication.

    As a GNU sed extension, the special value /dev/stdin is supported for 
    the file name, which reads the contents of the standard input.
```

For example,

```
$ sed '3r /dev/stdin' 123.txt < <(sed -n '2,4p' abc.txt)
1
2
3
b
c
d
4
5
```

Comment: The `r` command is in POSIX. The only thing that isn't POSIX (but is common even on non-GNU systems) in the sed part is `/dev/stdin`. If you use a pipe instead of a command substitution, your shell snippet is POSIX apart from the requirement that `/dev/stdin` exist.

Comment: The answer command gives the desired result on FreeBSD (a non-GNU system) as well.

Answer (score 3):

By using `awk` and `sed`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==3{print;system("sed -n '2,4p' abc.txt");next};1' 123.txt 
1
2
3
b
c
d
4
5
```

Answer (score 2):

In-place editing using`ed` and `sed` (on the bash prompt):

```
ed -s 123.txt<<<$'3r !sed -n "2,4p" abc.txt\nw'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you can use the `r` command to insert a whole file. To insert a part of a file, extract that part and pipe it as input to `sed`. You can use `sed` to do the extraction as well.

```
sed -n '2,4p' abc.txt | sed -i '3r /dev/stdin' 123.txt
```

With `awk`, you can read one file and switch to another file in the middle.

```
awk <123.txt >123.txt.new '
    1                                    # print the input line
    NR==3 {                              # after line 3 of 123.txt, …
        while (getline < "abc.txt") {
            ++inner_NR;
            if (inner_NR >= 2) print;    # start printing at line 2 from abc.txt
            if (inner_NR == 4) break;    # stop after line 4
        }
    }
' &&
mv 123.txt.new 123.txt
```

You can also use `head` and `tail` to extract the parts of the files that you want to combine.

```
head -n 3 <123.txt >123.txt.new &&
<abc.txt tail -n +2 | head -n 3 >>123.txt.new &&
tail -n +4 123.txt >>123.txt.new &&
mv 123.txt.new 123.txt
```

You can combine the `head`+`tail` approach with `sed`. For huge files, this is likely to be the fastest.

```
<abc.txt tail -n +2 | head -n 3 | sed -i '3r /dev/stdin' 123.txt
```

Note that all these approaches write to a temporary file which is moved to `123.txt` (even the approaches using `sed -i`, because that's what `sed -i` does under the hood).